# In Perl, how can I iterate over multiple elements of an array?

Tags: perl

I have a CSV file that I use `split` to parse into an array of `N` items, where `N` is a multiple of `3`.

Is there a way i can do this

```
foreach my ( $a, $b, $c ) ( @d ) {}
```

similar to Python?

Comment: Don't use `$a` and `$b` for variable names. Their are specially packaged scope variables for use with `sort`.

Comment: That would be cool if you could do that, though.

Comment: if you're outside of sort, it's fine. but if it's a one-liner you're going to reuse, possibly in sort later, then be careful, true. :-)

Comment: Please don't parse CSV files "by hand" -- use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV), which takes care of all the annoying little edge cases that will eventually bite you in the behind.

Comment: @eruciform => the danger is if you lexicalize `$a` or `$b` with `my`, and then later call `sort` in the same scope, `sort` will blow up, complaining that it can't localize a lexical variable

Comment: thx, i did not do this in code, was for demonstration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [List::MoreUtils::natatime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils). From the docs:

```
my @x = ('a' .. 'g');
my $it = natatime 3, @x;
while (my @vals = $it->()) {
    print "@vals\n";
}
```

`natatime` is implemented in XS so you should prefer it for efficiency. Just for illustration purposes, here is how one might implement a three element iterator generator in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @v = ('a' .. 'z' );

my $it = make_3it(\@v);

while ( my @tuple = $it->() ) {
    print "@tuple\n";
}

sub make_3it {
    my ($arr) = @_;
    {
        my $lower = 0;
        return sub {
            return unless $lower < @$arr;
            my $upper = $lower + 2;
            @$arr > $upper or $upper = $#$arr;
            my @ret = @$arr[$lower .. $upper];
            $lower = $upper + 1;
            return @ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: heh funny, didn't know about that one. probably a one-line closure around splice. :-)

Comment: @eruciform: in logic, yes, but the functions in List::Util and List::MoreUtils are written in XS for maximum speed. It really does pay off to use the exact function you need rather than using the builtin functions, when parsing a huge amount of data.

Comment: @eruciform: Actually, no. The functions in `List::MoreUtils` are implemented in XS (that is, C) to provide the maximum possible efficiency. The use of `splice` introduces a lot of memory overhead and moving pointers around etc which one might notice if *N* is large enough.

Comment: @sinan: nice, i didn't know about this utility library. of course xs is faster. :-)

Comment: @eruciform: the XS module isn't.  However, the pure perl version of List::MoreUtils is exactly as you describe: a closure around a copy of the list, with a splice. :)

Answer (score 14):

I addressed this issue in my module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen) on CPAN.

```
use List::Gen qw/by/;

for my $items (by 3 => @list) {

    # do something with @$items which will contain 3 element slices of @list

    # unlike natatime or other common solutions, the elements in @$items are
    # aliased to @list, just like in a normal foreach loop

}
```

You could also import the `mapn` function, which is used by `List::Gen` to implement `by`:

```
use List::Gen qw/mapn/;

mapn {

   # do something with the slices in @_

} 3 => @list;
```

Comment: are they actually aliased in a "for my"? or just in a "for" loop? the "my" is supposed to make a copy. does "by" get around this?

Comment: the `my` variable in a Perl foreach loop is never a copy, it is always an alias.  A lexically scoped alias, but an alias none the less.

Comment: All I can say is *very nice!*

Comment: Just reiterating Sinan's comment. This module looks really interesting. Great work.

Answer (score 5):

```
my @list = (qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine));

while (my ($m, $n, $o) = splice (@list,0,3)) {
  print "$m $n $o\n";
}
```

this outputs:

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@z=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);

for( @tuple=splice(@z,0,3); @tuple; @tuple=splice(@z,0,3) ) 
{ 
  print "$tuple[0] $tuple[1] $tuple[2]\n"; 
}
```

produces:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
0
```

Comment: this destroys the `@z` array and is probably better written as a while loop

Comment: @eric: true. this is a quickie solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. You'd be better off making `@d` an array of three-element tuples, by pushing the elements onto the array as an array reference:

```
foreach my $line (<>)
    push @d, [ split /,/, $line ];
```

(Except that you really ought to use one of the CSV modules from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

As of Perl v5.36 you can do exactly that:

```perl
foreach my ( $a, $b, $c ) ( @d ) { ... }
```

It's implemented as `for_list` experimental feature, so you can ignore the warning the usual way with `use experimental qw(for_list)`;

For versions before v5.36 we'll rely on `while/splice` as mentioned above.